# Intelligent storage system

Tags: macos, storage

I have a Macbook with 256GB as I'm studying I have a huge amount of documents piling up, taking more and more space. Most of them I'd like to keep, still often I don't need them so often.

Is there a program that remembers how often I use a file/folder and if it's untouched for a certain amount of time it get's zipped and after some more time it'll be uploaded on the Cloud. I'd like to see then like all my files and folders but some are marked as zipped or uploaded.

Let's say you have one that is uploaded then when clicking on it it'll be downloaded without me noticing really and the process restarts again.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's iCloud drive will do the first and last steps (not the intermediate zipping)

See Apples [site](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206985) section "Store your files in iCloud and save space on your device"

However it will cost as given [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201238)

I would also note that most docs are only megabytes if that unless you are using videos or large data sets for computing. So it might help to say what documents.